# How to fix "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

Tags: javascript, html

I'm learning how to make an autocomplete search bar from a video tutorial. I did everything the video did to no avail. I think the problem is with add.EventListener. When I run the code in Chrome, in console it shows:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Code:

```
searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
const input = searchInput.value;
suggestionsPanel.innerHTML = '';
const suggestions = movies.filter(function(movie) {
  return movie.name.toUpperCase().startsWith(input);
});
suggestions.forEach(function(suggested){
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = suggested;
  suggestionsPanel.appendChild(div);
});
if (input=== ''){
  suggestionsPanel='';
} })
```

This is the the JavaScript code and below is the HTML code to see any mistakes.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="icon" href="Geofflixlogo.png">
    <title>Geofflix</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="geofflix.css">
    <script src="geofflix.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="index.html">
            <img src="Logo.png" height="50">
            </a>
        <div class="navi">
            Watch what everyone's talking about. For Free!        
        </div>
        <div class="searchbar">
                <input class="search-input" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
                <div class="suggestions">
                </div>                
        </div>      
        <div class="nav">
                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                <a href="Movies.html">Movies</a>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: It would help to see the definition for `searchInput`

Comment: This means `searchInput` does not contain the reference to an element that you think it does.

Comment: also `suggestionsPanel` -))

Comment: you can solve using the right selectore for input search-input in this way `document.getElementByClassName('search-input')[0].addEventListener('keyup', function() {.....}` but only if there is only 1 input.search-input otherwise you have to add an unique ID to the field and use `document.getElementById('input_id')`

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea, where your bug comes from, but look on my function, seems to be ok.

```
let searchInput = document.querySelector('.search-input');
let suggestionsPanel = document.querySelector('.suggestions')
searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
 const input = searchInput.value;
 suggestionsPanel.innerHTML = input;
});
```

And working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/70ynvh4r/1/